# Word VBA Shapes Using Item

Tags: vba, ms-word, shapes

I've got the following code:

```
Sub removeTopAndBottomMostShapesFromActiveDocument()

Dim shape As shape
Dim topShape As shape
Dim bottomShape As shape

Dim pageNum
For pageNum = 1 To ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages.Count

    Dim highestPoint, lowestPoint
    highestPoint = 999999
    lowestPoint = -999999

    Set topShape = Nothing
    Set bottomShape = Nothing

    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Set sr =  ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(pageNum).Rectangles.Item(1).Range.ShapeRange
    sr.Select
    For Each shape In sr
        If shape.Top < highestPoint Then
            Set topShape = shape
            highestPoint = shape.Top
        End If
        If shape.Top + shape.Height > lowestPoint Then
            Set bottomShape = shape
            lowestPoint = shape.Top + shape.Height
        End If
    Next

    If Not topShape Is Nothing Then
        topShape.Delete
    End If
    If Not bottomShape Is Nothing Then
        bottomShape.Delete
    End If
```

With `Set sr = Activewindow` ... I can't figure out what the `.item(1)` does.  I've got textboxes in the Word document that are all the same.  On some pages `.item(1)` will give an `sr.count` of "0" but if I change to `.item(2)` or `.item(3)` the textboxes will be found on the specific page.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found a workaround.  For some reason the text boxes are being place in different items even though they are created by the exact same process.  If someone can explain this I'd be grateful.  So the solution is to create a loop with .Item(i) from 1 to 3 which grabs all the boxes on the pages and seems to work without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of Item 2 here:

http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html

We have done a lot of work with Word lately and it behaves as the article says in that Word and Pages do not go well together.

That .Items(1) should provide all the rectangles on that page, but I suspect it is getting confused about pages (bearing in mind every time you delete a shape the entire document will move and shapes that were on one page will now be on another).

I would also question the validity of what you are trying to do. If one person has a much higher resolution than another, presumably shapes that were at the top and bottom of a page on one persons machine might not be there on another persons machine.